# Django app working locally anyhow when I push it to Heroke it will display a 500 error (H10)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I started my Django app with the sqlite default data base and later on I proceeded the steps (shown below) since I wanted to host it in Pythonanywhere since it was a cheaper alternative (it did not work), I sadly could not successfully deploy to Heroku as well.
My project Repository looks like this:

```
   RECIPE-APP/
     |-include/
     |-Lib/
     |-Scripts/
     |-src/
      |-media/recipes/
      |-recipe_app/
       |-settings.py
       |-wsgi.py
      |-recipes/
     |-.env
     |-data.json
     |-db.sqlite3
     |-manage.py
    |-.gitatributes
    |-.gitignore
    |-Procfile
    |-pyvenv.cfg
    |-requirements.txt
```

I have a .env set up containing all keys for the DATABASES, in which case I copied all the required keys to heroku config vars. I reviewed the Procfile and it should be ok.
Procfile: `web: gunicorn src.recipe_app.wsgi --log-file -`

settings.py:

```
    """
    Django settings for recipe_app project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.6.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
    """

    from pathlib import Path
    import os
    import dotenv
    from decouple import config
    # import environ
    # from dotenv import load_dotenv


    # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # initialize environment variable
    # env = environ.Env()
    # reading .env file
    # environ.Env.read_env(env_file=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'src', '.env'))
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY','django-insecure-    ml49cp(e)=yakpevh4xz)3w)6xuq6kv7g&3^xf^)gr-n3&p#%9')

    DEBUG=config('DEBUG')

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['https://recipe-app-new-ccb69d876db5.herokuapp.com/', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django_extensions',
     'recipes'
    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

     ROOT_URLCONF = 'recipe_app.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
     {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
         },
     },
    ]

     WSGI_APPLICATION = 'recipe_app.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases
    # configuration for Heroku
    DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3' 
               } 
    }

    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
     },
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
     },
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
     },
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
     },
   ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

    MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


    # Default primary key field type
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

    DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    import dj_database_url
    db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
    DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

the variation that works locally requires only:

```
    DATABASES = {
            'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME' : config('DB_NAME'),
            'USER' : config('DB_USER'),
            'PASSWORD' : config('DB_PASSWORD'), 
            'HOST' : config('DB_HOST'),
            'PORT' : config('DB_PORT')
    }
    }
```

avoiding:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
     import dj_database_url
     db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
    DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

&

```
DATABASES = {
      'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3' 
              } 
        }
```

I am getting some help from a Fullstack Developer anyhow we are not really being able to find the error.
I have checked:
Procfile, Debug set as False,and the rest of files for possible issues and in theory they seem ok.
Error Logs (Heroku):

```
heroku logs --tail
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.064093+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-11-22 20:55:06 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting      worker with pid: 8
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.096683+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-11-22 20:55:06 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker   (pid:7) exited with code 3
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157262+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-11-22 20:55:06 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157263+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157264+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site- packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157265+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157265+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157265+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157265+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157266+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157266+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157266+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi        
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157266+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157267+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157267+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load     
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157267+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157267+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157267+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157267+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157267+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157268+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app     
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157268+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157268+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157269+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157285+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157285+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157285+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157285+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157286+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157286+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157286+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157287+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157287+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/src/recipe_app/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157287+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157287+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157287+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157287+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157288+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157288+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157288+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157288+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157288+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157288+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in _setup   
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157289+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157289+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157289+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 217, in __init__
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157289+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157289+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157289+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157290+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157290+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157290+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157290+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in  _find_and_load
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157290+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157290+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157290+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157291+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157291+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157291+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'recipe_app'
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.157347+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-11-22 20:55:06 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193157+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-11-22 20:55:06 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) exited with code 3
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193216+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193225+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193370+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193407+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep       
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193479+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193551+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193560+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld 
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193603+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193619+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193690+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193752+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193752+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193753+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193754+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193762+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193762+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193800+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193822+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193830+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run      
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193866+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193884+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 236, in run        
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193927+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193947+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193975+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.193989+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194031+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194053+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt        
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194119+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194131+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 396, in stop        
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194186+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194200+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld 
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194236+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194247+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers2023-11-22T20:55:06.194319+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.194334+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.272151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2023-11-22T20:55:06.292585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2023-11-22T20:55:11.852622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=recipe-app-new-ccb69d876db5.herokuapp.com request_id=e047b986-ee63-47b0-9b56-8f42e6334382 fwd="88.65.108.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2023-11-22T20:55:12.055491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=recipe-app-new-ccb69d876db5.herokuapp.com request_id=da0b55bc-7c9e-4a33-a75e-87054e8f08b6 fwd="88.65.108.50" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: `Lib` and `Scripts` definitely shouldn't be pushed to Heroku. Do you have a virtual environment committed?

Comment: The error says that _your_ Python package cannot be found.  This indicates that the PYTHONPATH is not getting set up correctly when it runs at Heroku.  Make sure you've got things configured correctly for having code located in directory: 'src'.  Not sure how this works on Heroku, but I would expect this to be configured via your Procfile or possibly via a setup.cfg or pyproject.toml file

Comment: I do have a virtual environment, I believe the path is in another folder.
Thanks @Chris

Comment: Ha, hiya @BillHuneke! Small world. We should grab a beer sometime.

Comment: Hey have you been able to resolve this?

Comment: Hi thanks for checking up, I had use again anew database. So to speak I erased what I had and from there it worked. I reseted the migrations as well.